# A way to install an extension without copying the files. Magento

Tags: magento

Sorry. I'm pretty new to Magento extension development. I wonder if there is a method to install my extension, including copying the files and put it in place. I know that i can create an install script for the SQL updates but I wanna to not explain to my client that before to run the script he should put all the extension files in the appropriate folder.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Magento Composer Installer: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer